# Can you explain the context dependent variable assignment in perl

Tags: perl, variables, syntax, variable-assignment

The following is one of the many cool things that Perl can do

```
my ($tmp) = ($_=~ /^>(.*)/);
```

It finds the pattern ^>.* in the current line in a loop, and it stores the what's in the parenthesis in the $tmp variable.

What I am curious is the concept behind this syntax. How and why(under what premises) does this work?
My understanding is the snippet $_=~ /^>(.*)/ is a boolean context, but the parenthesis renders it as a list context?  But how come only what is in the parenthesis in the matched pattern is stored in the variable?!

Is it some kind of special case of variable assignments I have to "memorize" or can this be perfectly explainable? if so, what is this feature called(name like "autovivifacation?")

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: the parentheses around `$tmp` are vital as they impose list context on the `=~` operator. Without them a true or false scalar value (`1` or `''`) would be assigned depending on the success of failure of the pattern match.

Comment: It's really odd to see `$_ =~`. It is a well known default.

Comment: @ikegami I see. I am still a perl newbie. Can that be re-written as `code` my ($tmp) = (/^>(.*)/); `code` ??

Comment: @Alby, yup! Or just `my ($tmp) = /^>(.*)/;`

Comment: To answer your direct questions: Each operator is free to return whatever it wants to. Yes, you have to memorize what each operator returns, or at least check perlop. It's not a feature that different operators do different things, so it doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two assignment operators: list assignment and scalar assignment. The choice is determined based on the LHS of the "`=`". (The two operators are covered in detail in [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129).)

---

In this case, a list assignment operator is used. The list assignment operator evaluates both of its operands in list context.

So what does `$_=~ /^>(.*)/` do in list context? Quote [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> If the `/g` option is not used, `m//` in list context returns a list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the pattern, i.e., (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`...) [...] When there are no parentheses in the pattern, the return value is the list `(1)` for success. With or without parentheses, an empty list is returned upon failure.

In other words,

```
my ($match) = $_ =~ /^>(.*)/;
```

is equivalent to

```
my $match;
if ($_ =~ /^>(.*)/) {
    $match = $1;
} else {
    $match = undef;
}
```

---

Were the parens omitted (`my $tmp = ...;`), a scalar assignment would be used instead. The scalar assignment operator evaluates both of its operands in scalar context.

So what does `$_=~ /^>(.*)/` do in scalar context? Quote [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails.

In other words,

```
my $matched = $_ =~ /^>(.*)/;
```

is equivalent to

```
my $matched;
if ($_ =~ /^>(.*)/) {
    $matched = 1;   # !!1 if you want to be picky.
} else {
    $matched = 0;   # !!0 if you want to be picky.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The brackets in the search pattern make that a "group".  What `$_ =~ /regex/`returns is an array of all the matching groups, so `my ($tmp)` grabs the first group into $tmp.

Comment: if there was no parenthesis in the regular expression, what does it return?

Comment: @Alby, `(1)` on success. `()` if the match fails (whether captures where used or not).

Comment: @ikegami Thanks! So to summarize, if there is at least one sub-expression wrapped around by parentheses, it returns the list of the subexpressions, and if there isn't any subexpressions it returns either 1 or 0 depending on the success of the match against the whole regular expression. Am I correct?

Comment: @Alby, empty list, not zero (which would end up assigning `undef` to `$tmp`). Otherwise, yes, that's correct. This should be very clear in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

All operations in perl have a return value, including assignment.  Thats why you can do `$a=$b=1` and set `$a` to the result of `$b=1`.

You can use `=~` in a boolean (well, scalar) context, but that's just because it returns an empty list / undef if there's no match, and that evaluates to false.  Calling it in an array context returns an array, just like other context-sensitive functions can do using the wantarray method to determine context.